# Does a 1D array work as a list of strings, or a single string?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    char a[10];
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        scanf("%s",a);// >how this line is working in memory.
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In the above code, I would like to know how the string is saved in memory, since I have initialised it as a 1D character array, but does the array work as a list of strings, or a single string? Why?

Comment: do you think the loop makes any sense? you're overwriting the same location over and over again.

Comment: an array becomes a string once it is null-terminated. for an uninitialized automatic `char` array, it can never be called a string.

Comment: What do you find when you observe `a` in a debugger?

Answer (score 5):

In C, a *string* is a sequence of character values terminated by a 0-valued character - IOW, the string `"Hello"` is represented as the character sequence `'H'`, `'e'`, `'l'`, `'l'`, `'o'`, `0`.  Strings are *stored* in arrays of `char` (or `wchar_t` for *wide strings*):

```
char str[] = "Hello";
```

In memory, `str` would look something like this:

```
     +---+
str: |'H'| str[0]
     +---+
     |'e'| str[1]
     +---+
     |'l'| str[2]
     +---+
     |'l'| str[3]
     +---+
     |'o'| str[4]
     +---+
     | 0 | str[5]
     +---+
```

It is possible to store multiple strings in a single 1D array, although almost nobody does this:

```
char strs[] = "foo\0bar";
```

In memory:

```
      +---+
strs: |'f'| strs[0]
      +---+
      |'o'| strs[1]
      +---+
      |'o'| strs[2]
      +---+
      | 0 | strs[3]
      +---+
      |'b'| strs[4]
      +---+
      |'a'| strs[5]
      +---+
      |'r'| strs[6]
      +---+
      | 0 | strs[7]
      +---+
```

The string `"foo"` is stored starting at `strs[0]`, while the string `"bar"` is stored starting at `strs[4]`.

Normally, to store an array of *strings*, you'd either use a 2D array of `char`:

```
char strs[][MAX_STR_LEN] = { "foo", "bar", "bletch" };
```

or a 1D array of pointers to `char`:

```
char *strs[] = { "foo", "bar", "bletch" };
```

In the first case, the contents of the string are stored within the `strs` array:

```
      +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
strs: |'f'|'o'|'o'| 0 | ? | ? | ? |
      +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
      |'b'|'a'|'r'| 0 | ? | ? | ? |
      +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
      |'b'|'l'|'e'|'t'|'c'|'h'| 0 |
      +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

In the second, each `strs[i]` *points* to a different, 1D array of `char`:

```
      +---+                 +---+---+---+---+
strs: |   | strs[0] ------> |'f'|'o'|'o'| 0 |
      +---+                 +---+---+---+---+
      |   | strs[1] ----+
      +---+             |   +---+---+---+---+
      |   | strs[2] -+  +-> |'b'|'a'|'r'| 0 |
      +---+          |      +---+---+---+---+
                     |
                     |      +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
                     +----> |'b'|'l'|'e'|'t'|'c'|'h'| 0 |
                            +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

In your code, `a` can (and is usually intended to) store a single string that's 9 characters long (not counting the 0 terminator).  Like I said, almost nobody stores multiple strings in a single 1D array, but it is possible (in this case, `a` can store 2 4-character strings).

Comment: Great answer. Now I feel like I should remove mine :D

Answer (score 2):

```
char a[10];
```

You've allocated 10 bytes of the stack for `a`. But right now, it contains garbage because you never gave it a value.

`Scanf` doesn't know any of this. All it does is copy bytes from the standard input into `a`, ignorant of its size.

And why are you doing a loop 10 times? You will overwrite `a` each loop iteration, so you'll only have the value from the final time.

Comment: Are you mixing up `scanf` and `printf`? `scanf` reads nothing from `a`, it will write to it.

Comment: @mch fixed [15 chars]

Answer (score 2):

A string is per definition a null-terminated character array. So every character array becomes a string as soon as it contains a `\0` somewhere, defining the end of that string.

In memory the string is just a bunch of bytes laying (for simplicity but not necessarily) in sequence. Take the string `"Hello"` for example

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| H | e | l | l | o | \0|  
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Your array `char a[10]` is pointing to the beginning of such a memory location ('H' in the example) with enough space to store 10 characters.
By using `scanf` you are storing an string (character sequence + terminating `\0`) in that buffer (over and over again). `scanf` stores the characters in there and adds a terminating `\0` to the element after the last one written to. This allows you to safely store any character sequence that is at most 9 characters long, since the 10th character needs to be the `\0`

Answer (score 1):

You are over-writing same buffer in loop 10 times, which means buffer will contain data entered in last reading and previous 9 strings will be lost.

Also entering more than 9 characters would cause buffer overflow which would invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You should limit number of characters scanned from input buffer and then [clear the rest of the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7898215/how-to-clear-input-buffer-in-c). (Not `fflush(stdin);`)

```
scanf("%9s",a);
```

> Does a 1D array work as a list of strings, or a single string?

If its terminated with null character then yes, its string, like this. And `a` is the address of first element.

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+
| S | t | r | i | n | g | \0 | 
+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+
  a  a+1 a+2
```

And if you pass this array ie. to `printf()`, he will print all characters until he reach `\0`.

If you would like to read list of strings, you have to declare *2D array* or *pointer-to-pointer-to-char* and allocate enough memory for pointers.

```
int c;
char a[10][10];
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    scanf("%9s",a[i]);
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) ;
}
```

Comment: In fact, he is overwriting it 10 times.

Comment: Yes but i mean entered data

Comment: *You are over-writing same buffer in loop 9 times.* No, he is doing it `10` times.

Answer (score 1):

> Does a 1D array work as a list of strings, or a single string?

quite broad question.

`char a[10];` declared table a which has a size of 10 the `char` elements

`char *a[10];` declared table a which has a size of 10 `char *` elements which can possible point to the string (when you allocate memory for it and copy the valid C string)

In your code:
'scanf("%s",a);' `a` means the address of the first element of the array. So scanf writes data there, every time overwriting the previous content. If your scanf-ed input will need more 10 elements (including trailing `0`) to be stored, you will get an UB and very possible SEGFAUT